# Twitter Oauth not directing to twitter login page

Tags: node.js, twitter, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I have an app I'd like to use twitter Oauth and authenticate a user. I scaffolded the app with yeoman angular-fullstack generator.

When I click connect with twitter I'm receiving this error. I'm not reaching a Twitter login screen.

> Error: Could not authenticate you.
>       at Strategy.parseErrorResponse

Here is the route setup

```
router
  .get('/', passport.authenticate('twitter', {
    failureRedirect: '/signup',
    session: false
  }))
  .get('/callback', passport.authenticate('twitter', {
    failureRedirect: '/signup',
    session: false
  }), setTokenCookie);
```

I went to twitter and registered my app and used the Access Token and Access Token Secret for the consumerKey and consumerSecret respectively. Here is the Passport setup.

```
    export function setup(User, config) {
      passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
        consumerKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',  
        consumerSecret: 'zzzzzzzzzzz',  
        callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/twitter/callback' 
      },
```

Appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: did u get any solution?

Answer (score 1):

ok needed to use consumer key and consumer secret. Not the access tokens.